# Fusion Table set format for DATETIME

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am using google-api-services-fusiontables-v1-rev1-1.7.2-beta from my Android application.
I am using the insert raw sql api service.query().sql("INSERT INTO " + tableId +" (DATE, HOUR, PULS,SYS, DIA) VALUES (long, long, int, int, int) and have some questions.

1. The getDateTime() is of type long and given in millisecond. However the data in fusion table all the time showing 31 DEC, 1969 and the hour is all the time 6PM. Is this a known issue?
2. Is there a way to set the format of DATETIME from my application, I haven't seen a JSON field or an api to set the format...?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Fusion Table team. Can someone please help with the questions?

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what getDateTime() method you're using?  Could you give a code snippet showing how you're calling the API, and where you see 31 DEC, 1969 6PM?

Also, currently you are not able to set the date format.  Feel free star the following feature request: http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=727&q=Type%3DFeature_Request%20format%20date&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Stars%20Component

Comment: We are using the System.currentTimeMillis() (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html) for the getDateTime(). When we check the date on FusionTable any format other then number we are getting the wrong date of 31 DEC, 1969 6PM.

Comment: Could you include some code to show how you are inserting dates and how you are getting the wrong dates?

Comment: Here is what I am using for inserting raw into a table. service.query().sql("INSERT INTO " + tableId +
                                " (DATE, HOUR, WEIGHT) VALUES " + "(" + System.currentTimeMillis()  + "," +
                                System.currentTimeMillis()  + "," + oAuth2.getWeight() + ")"); The DATE and HOUR Columns are from DATETIME type. Now when going to the table online from my GDrive, and changing the format of the coulmns to be with an hour or a date format (e.g. 10 DEC, 2012) the date displays as  31 DEC, 1969.

Comment: you can look at https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?classic=true&docid=1tRkT8t34DRkJfeZ03zxl-yLW-I0CadSF_dYl5RM , ask for access and look at raw 4, to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

31 DEC, 1969 6PM is the unix epoc in Central Standard Time.

Fusion Tables does not recognize the UNIX epoch long values returned by System.currentTimeMillis() as dates. It recognizes them as numbers. Fusion does however recognize a set of textual formats automatically. You can see which formats are supported  using the browser interface in the change column dialog box under date formats. For example I use the format "2008-12-25 10:30:45". To format a date in Java into a certain text format you can use SimpleDateFormat. Just insert the string version of the date into the SQL.

There is no way to set the format options of a column from the API, currently that can only be done from the Google Drive interface.

Remember that Fusion Tables is Experimental and may be discontinued in the future. Also be careful that you are not using Fusion Tables for anything other than purely non-profit purposes because it really is only intended for charity and public service use cases.